# Question about Power Series

Tags: calculus, power-series

I have this problem:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\ 64^n\ (x-10)^{3n+1}$$

After using the Ratio Test I am left with this:

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\big|\frac{64^{n+1}(x-10)^{3n+4}}{64^n(x-10)^{3n+1}}\big|
$$

When I simplify the problem... I get this

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\big|64(x-10)^3\big|
$$

There's no "$n$" in the problem left... what would be the interval of convergence? I feel like I might've made a mistake somewhere or I missed something in class. Any help would be awesome, thanks!

Comment: There is no "integral" of convergence. What do you mean?

Comment: Whoops meant interval of convergence! @AndresCaicedo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you're perfectly correct. What that means is that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} |64(x-10)^3| = |64(x-10)^3|$$

So you can find the interval of convergence the way you normally do: finding those $x$ such that $|64(x-10)^3| < 1$.

Comment: I was just so used to seeing "n" and taking the limit of them that I was so confused at this step. This clears it up thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since you solved the problem, I just add for your curiosity that the summation has a very nicely surprising closed form  $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\ 64^n\ (x-10)^{3n+1}=\frac{x-10}{(41-4 x) \left(16 x^2-316 x+1561\right)}$$

Comment: Why surprising? Is a geometric series thinly disguised.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla. I wanted to mean "nicely surprising"